# Magento 2.2.5 checkout page custom field value not getting in Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, onepage-checkout

Triggered "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action" event but custom checkout field value not getting in observer.

How can I save checkout page custom field data with other checkout details to a custom table using observer.

Created a "sms" custom field on checkout page

```
namespace EdmondsCommerce\Sms\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;

class SmsPlugin
{
    public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout) {
        $customAttributeCode = 'sms';
        $customField = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                // customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'customEntry' => null,
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes' . '.' . $customAttributeCode,
            'label' => 'Custom SMS Attribute',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => 0,
            'validation' => [
                'required-entry' => true
            ],
            'options' => [],
            'filterBy' => null,
            'customEntry' => null,
            'visible' => true,
        ];

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $customField;

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Extension attribute code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="sms" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

   <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="checkout_onepage_observer" instance="EdmondsCommerce\Sms\Observer\TestObserver" />
    </event>
```

Observer Code

```
namespace EdmondsCommerce\Sms\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class TestObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_checkoutSession;


    public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation) {


        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_addressInformation = $addressInformation;

    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){

        $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();


        $shippingAddress = $this->_addressInformation->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddressExtensionAttributes = $shippingAddress->getExtensionAttributes();
        if ($shippingAddressExtensionAttributes) {
            $sms = $shippingAddressExtensionAttributes->getSms();
            echo $sms;
            exit();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not Proper way for add custom field,also you missed js file to override  `Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information.js`

Check it [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html)

**Edit**
1. It look like you are adding order attribute,so you have to save that value in `quote` and `order` table.
2. get that value from address extension attribute by plugin method.

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
      <plugin name="save_to_quote_table" type="EdmondsCommerce\Sms\Plugin\Quote\SaveToQuote" sortOrder="10"/>
   </type>
...
class SaveToQuote
{...
...
public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
       \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
       $cartId,
       \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
   ) {

       if(!$extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes())
           return;
       $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

       $quote->setSms($extAttributes->getSms());
   }
}
```

in that function of class you have to set it in qoute then you can assign value to order from quote in your observer.
May be it helps.(don't forget to compile)

Comment: js files also included, not mentioned above
/app/code/EdmondsCommerce/Sms/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin.js
/app/code/EdmondsCommerce/Sms/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Comment: Please help me to solve the issue...
I want to add a custom field on checkout page and save all the details to a custom table

Comment: i have update answer